# JSON: key items by id or not?

Tags: json

I've been charged with creating a simple data source so clients can retrieve a list of things by JSON.  Each thing has an ID, so my first impulse was to create something like

```
{
    "13": {
        "name": "foo",
        "height": 17
    },
    "18": {
        "name": "bar",
        "height": 22
    }
...
}
```

But I've been told that this is an abuse of JS properties as an associative array, so that something like this would be more appropriate:

```
[
    {
        "id": 13,
        "name": "foo",
        "height": 17 
    },
    {
        "id": 18,
        "name": "bar",
        "height": 22 
    }
]
```

The second version just seems... difficult.  What's the best practice here?

Comment: Why would this be an abuse? Seems to me like a very legitimate use.

Comment: "so clients can retrieve a list of things by JSON" what you gave is NOT list of things, it's dictionary (map)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The common way of doing it is the latter and there are virtually no benefits from doing the former. At most you've saved the consumer of your API about five keystrokes, at worst you created an API that is far less than self explanatory. i.e. Is that key the item's Id? Is it some other sort of identifier? Is it unique only for this request? Etc.

Comment: I can see a benefit - with PHP after the json_decode(), i can get $mystuff[13]. How do I do this - access only the one element - without extra looping to index the array/object with the common way?

Answer (score 13):

If you want to access the object via the ID, use the former variant with the ID as property name. Then you can directly access that object using the object’s ID. Otherwise, if you need to work with all objects anyway, use the latter variant.

Comment: I don't really know how clients will use this data yet.

Comment: From my work experience, the former creates a real problem for clients (apps in my case) to parse the JSON data, as it cannot be done the normal way and all the keys have to be iterated and parsed into objects by hand. However, on the second approach, the client can parse they objects as native language objects with ease.

However, my Backend colelagues argue that using the former helps them map the data, when they need to combine it with other APIs. I'm still not sure what is the convention, but I;m convinced that the second way is much more developer and compiuter friendly.

Answer (score 0):

These are different use cases, the standard should be as the second and in some cases, the first one. When ? when you want to access by key and avoid looping thru. Probably the first case should be for internal use only, and the second one (current standard) for external exposure. Both valid.

Answer (score 0):

Note that the former one puts it's objects inside an object `{}` while the latter puts them into an array `[]`. Putting them in an array could be used if you need all the items. And the former one could be used if you would like to access them with the id.